# Is there any editor or popular editor extension that automatically remove quotes/brackets?

Tags: editor, text-editor, quotes, double-quotes, brackets

There are too many text editors, which have the function, that if I just select a piece of the code and press the quote/bracket key, the selected code becomes wrapped into the type of the quotes/brackets I pressed. But do you know any or are you using any, which has also the function, that if I select the piece of the code wrapped into the quotes/brackets and press the same quote/bracket key or some key combination, that piece of code becomes unwrapped?

Also if you know any editor or popular editor extension that automatically remove all quotes/brackets from the code, please write it too. Everything would be helpful.

We are doing some research and this question is still unanswered. Please help us if you know anything about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've made it by writing my own extension to my favourite editor.

Answer (score 1):

I create a simple *Zeus (Windows)* Lua script that does this for the quote case (i.e. the macro wraps any marked area in quotes).

In a similar fashion another script could be written for the brackets case.

Also as this simple script shows, this should be possible in any scriptable editor.

The script can be found here: http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=7148

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite editor (Windows) can do scripting for u. You can write Python plugin in 10min, and assign it a hotkey, so selection (or all text) will dequote, or what ever.